# Can you workaound top-level await bug in Storybook using the BSON library?

Tags: storybook, sveltekit-storybook

I have a Storybook project configured with [bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson). When I try to build, it fails with:

```
[vite:esbuild-transpile] Transform failed with 1 error:
assets/index.stories-!~{00F}~.js:12900:26: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
```

How can I solve this?

The error happens if I import `import {ObjectId} from 'bson';`.

I have created a repo [here](https://github.com/21RISK/svelte-story-bson), so it's easy to test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the issue you made in [`storybookjs/storybook` issue 25399](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/25399) is enough:

[Jeppe Reinhold](https://github.com/JReinhold)  (who also wrote "[Storybook for SvelteKit](https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-for-sveltekit/)" in Feb. 2023) adds:

> We don't include the `build` property of a user's Vite config because it has a high risk of colliding with Storybook's build settings - see [diff commit 0a86cd2](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/commit/0a86cd2f2cc586c0ee02186ebf2ea9c6d71f1452#diff-58844c0c6a00ae8bad85eb2369a25ae5b43f04c8262221bd9187d07159f0f87c)
>
> You can instead add the configuration you need like the build target to `viteFinal` in `main.ts`:
>
> ```
> const config = {
>     ...
>   viteFinal: async (config) => {
>       if(!config.build) {
>           config.build = {};
>       }
>       config.build.target = ['es2022', 'edge89', 'firefox89', 'chrome89', 'safari15'];
>       return config;
>   }
> };
> export default config;
> ```
>
> I did this in the repo and it worked.

So that would modify the Storybook's Vite configuration to explicitly set the build target to environments that support top-level await.
It allows you to continue using the BSON library in your SvelteKit Storybook project without the top-level await error.

The diff commit includes:

```
// I destructure away the `build` property from the user's config object
// I do this because I can contain config that breaks storybook, such as we had in a lit project.
// If the user needs to configure the `build` they need to do so in the viteFinal function in main.js.
```

Comment: Yes 100% - this actually made it work ✨